# NAV 2013 Automation Object not initialized?

Tags: automation, navision, dynamics-al, cal

so i have following problem and really dont know why it’s not working:

I create an automation in NAV 2013. For that, i use following code:
`CREATE(HTTPRequest,FALSE,TRUE);`

The HTTPRequest is a variable of DataType Automation and SubType 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.ServerXMLHTTP60

I can save and compile the codeunit, in which the automation is in it. So far so good.

But as soon as i want to try a connection test to our web servers, he tells me this:

> It is not possible to convert Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavAutomation to Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavInStream.

The debugger stops at following line of code:

`InStreamResponse := HTTPRequest.responseStream;`
InStreamResponse is DataType InStream.

So if I look in the HTTPRequest.responseStream variable, it looks like this:
[New Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6ekg.png)
I think the problem is, that the HTTPRequest variable is valued with “Automation” and so the ResponseText tells me its not available in the current context. When i look into another project of our company, the exact same HTTPRequest is valued as following:

[Old, working project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Gao.png)

Does anyone of you know why this is? As i said, i think its because the HTTPRequest isn’t valued with

```
'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.ServerXMLHTTP60
```

like in the working project. But why is this? I cant explain. Is there a fix which i need or did i forget something?

The only difference is, that on the current working code (2. screenshot) the HTTPRequest is created as following:

```
CREATE(HTTPRequest);
```

Whereas on my new project it needs to be declared as

```
CREATE(HTTPRequest,FALSE,TRUE);
```

Otherwise i cant complie the codeunit.

Comment: Since it's Nav 2013, why don't you just use dotnet variable? 

And why it has to be true in the second parameter of CREATE? Do you really want it to run on the client side?